# Problem with simplifying Sinc function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

```
$Assumptions = x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals && a ∈ Reals && b ∈ Reals;
```

These work:

```
Cos[x/2] Sinc[x/2] == Sinc[x] // FullSimplify
(* True *)

Cos[y/2] Sinc[y/2] == Sinc[y] // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```

but these don't:

```
Cos[x/2] Sinc[x/2] + Cos[y/2] Sinc[y/2] == Sinc[x] + Sinc[y] // FullSimplify
(* Cos[x/2] Sinc[x/2] + Cos[y/2] Sinc[y/2] == Sinc[x] + Sinc[y] *)

Cos[a + b] Sinc[a + b] == Sinc[2 (a + b)] // FullSimplify
(* Cos[a + b] Sinc[a + b] == Sinc[2 (a + b)] *)
```

Why this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, a preliminary application of `FunctionExpand[]` works wonders:

```
Cos[a + b] Sinc[a + b] == Sinc[2 (a + b)] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify
   True
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why MMA behavior like this? Why it have problem with `a+b` as an argument in `Sinc`?

Comment: It would seem that `FullSimplify[]` does not know everything about `Sinc[]`, so a preliminary application of `FunctionExpand[]` is needed to convert your expression in terms of functions `FullSimplify[]` can easily handle.

Answer (score 2):

You can try proceeding this way:

```
rule = Cos[x_] Sinc[x_] -> Sinc[2 x]

Cos[x/2] Sinc[x/2] + Cos[y/2] Sinc[y/2] == Sinc[x] + Sinc[y] /. rule
Cos[a + b] Sinc[a + b] == Sinc[2 (a + b)] /. rule
```

Which both give

```
True
```

as expected. Also note that your assumptions make no difference as

```
Cos[x/2] Sinc[x/2] == Sinc[x] // FullSimplify
```

gives `True` without any assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cos[a + b] Sinc[a + b] == Sinc[2 (a + b)] /. Sinc[x_] -> Sin[x]/x // Simplify
Cos[x/2] Sinc[x/2] + Cos[y/2] Sinc[y/2] == Sinc[x] + Sinc[y] 
 /.Sinc[x_] -> Sin[x]/x // Simplify

FullSimplify[ Cos[x/2] Sinc[x/2] + Cos[y/2] Sinc[y/2] == Sinc[x] + Sinc[y], 
   TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Reduce[#, {x, y}, Reals] &}]
```